# I lost 100 reputation points

Tags: discussion, support

I was quite busy for a few months and did not have any chance to check Arduino Stack Exchange and when I open today I have lost near about 120 points I don't know why and there is a message `Serial Voting corrected`. Is there any chance I can get back my lost reputation? Or do I need to earn them again?

Comment: Hey - yeah, Majenko's answer here is correct. It's seriously unfortunate, but was a necessary voting correction that affected a good number of users. If you or anyone else has questions about it, I'm happy to help answer them. Just poke me in the comments here.

Comment: No, thank you @Slate. It is now clear to me if I have any further doubts I will surely let you know. Thank you

Comment: I'm late to this question on meta, but I just realized, that I lost a whole 3600 in reputation. I was wondering but this answers it. Must have been a really bad rogue user to give me 3600 points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry, you're not alone. We had a rogue user that caused some trouble, and their bad behaviour has been corrected. Those 120 points you had are gone I'm afraid. But don't worry, some people lost thousands of rep.

Keep writing great answers and I'm sure you'll soon enough earn them back.